# Jquery Client Side Validation through Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, passwords, client-side-validation

I am trying to validate re-password input via jquery client side validation through asp.net mvc. I use modal for my form. I send the form data to asp.net using ajax method. Then I send the error message from server site to the modal. It works, but when the passwords don't match, the form doesn't accept the new password. Jquery compares the new password with the password I entered at first. I tried to reset the form data, but it didn't work. Is there anybody had that issue before or any idea?

JQUERY code;

```
$('#createConfirm').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();      

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: window.location.pathname,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#createModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#content-body').html(data);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    $('#createModal .modal-body').html(result);
                }
            }
       });
});
```

ASP.NET code;

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name!")]
        [Display(Name = "Name Surname")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-mail Address")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your e-mail!")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a username!")]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password!")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the password again!")]
        [Display(Name = "Password Confirm")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match")]
        public string RePassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a role!")]
        [Display(Name = "User Role")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; } 
        
        [Display(Name = "Role Description")]
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateUser(UserModel user)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();

                var account = new ApplicationUser();
                account.Name = user.Name;
                account.Email = user.Email;
                account.UserName = user.Username;

                IdentityResult result = userManager.Create(account, user.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = userManager.AddToRole(account.Id, user.RoleName);
                    TempData["MessageInfo"] = "User created successfully.";
                    return Json(new { success = true });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roleManager.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            user.Password = null;
            user.RePassword = null;

          return PartialView("_UserForm", user);
        }
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you locate the piece of code that doesn't work as expected and paste it here

Comment: Thank you  for your comment. I added the code.